# Send JSON from javascript to REST and add the content to database

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest

I am currently parsing a csv file to JSON format with help of PapaParser in javascript. I want to send this parsed JSON data using AJAX to a RESTful service which in turn will have to send the data to MySQL database.

I am not able to send the data to the RESTful service.

My javascript code is:`

```js
$('#submit').click(function()
{
  $("input[type=file]").parse({
    config: 
    {
      delimiter:",",
      header: true,
      dynamicTyping: true,
      skipEmptyLines: false,
      complete: function(result, file) 
      {
        console.log("This file done:", file);
        var emp=(JSON.stringify(result.data, null, 4));

        $.ajax( {
         url: 'http://localhost:8100/department/v1',
         data: result.data,
         datatype : "application/json",
         type: 'POST',
         dataType: 'JSON',
         success: function( returnObj ) {
          //FunctionDefinitionHere
          console.log(result.data);
         }
       });
   }
 }
});

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Add Employee | Allowance Processing System</title>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="PapaParse/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="PapaParse/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
 <p>Select an Excel Sheet with Employee Details</p>
 <br/>
 <form action="#" method="POST">
  <input type="file" name="file" id="file" accept=".csv" />
  <input type="submit" id="submit">
 </form>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="parse.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="PapaParse/papaparse.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="PapaParse/papaparse.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 `dataType` properties. I suspect you want `contentType` to be json which also requires you to send stringified data

Try

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://localhost:8100/department/v1',
  data: emp, // stringified json
  contentType: "application/json",
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'JSON',
  success: function(returnObj) {
    //FunctionDefinitionHere
    console.log(returnObj);
  }
});
```

Also add an error handler to help debug

Comment: Didn't work. Added error handler also. The ajax call fails everytime and rather than executing success function, it goes into error block.

Comment: Add an error handler to get more details as to why request fails. Also inspect actual request in browser dev tools network to see what is being sent is what is expected and check status, response body etc

Comment: request header
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:13
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host:localhost:8100
Origin:http://localhost:8100
Referer:http://localhost:8100/add_employee.html
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36
Form Data
view source
view URL encoded

Comment: that's a server side error for "method not allowed"